# Refactor if condition so that if and else block's logic gets interchanged

Tags: c#, if-statement, refactoring

In my Windows application, I have something as below.

```
bool somebooleanValue = getBooleanValue();
string someString = getStringValue();

if (!somebooleanValue && someString == "StringValue")
{
    //do nothing
}
else
{
    // do some calculations
}
```

Here, if the somebooleanValue is false and someString is equal to "StringValue", it has to skip the calculations that are to be done. So for that I have put a condition like above.

Now if I have to refactor the code  and change the condition, so that if block is not blank, how should I do that?

I have tried this

```
if !(!somebooleanValue && someString == "StringValue")
{
    //do some calculations
}
else
{
    // do nothing
}
```

But it is giving an error saying ") expected". I'm not able to figure out what is wrong. What can I try next?

Comment: You might want to save the entire if's clause condition to `somebooleanValue` and then do `if(somebooleanValue) {...}`

Comment: You have a syntax error. Plus, you may use [De Morgan transformations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to keep the code readable

Comment: As mentioned you are missing the outermost bracket, to simplify the condition further you can use `if (somebooleanValue || someString !="stringvalue")`. A good trick when converting the several && into || and vice versa is just to negate the individual condition and change && into or. Eg. for some condition A and B:  `(A && B) ~ (!A || !B)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a bracket inside the if condition. You should probably write:

```
if (!(!somebooleanValue && someString == "StringValue"))
{
    //do some calculations
}
else
{
   // do nothing
}
```

This will not give you the **") expected"** error.